# Fix append pgfplots style to all pictures breaking plain TikZ compilation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code in my preamble to align the pgfplots in my document.

```
\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        scale only axis
    },
    /tikz/every picture/.append style={
        trim axis left,
        trim axis right,
    }
}
```

But the last part (`/tikz/every picture/.append style...`) breaks compilation for TikZ picture that don't use pgfplots, since there is no axis in it.

Currently, I have to comment that part of the code, then compile all plain TikZ drawings, then uncomment and compile all pgfplots figures, then mix them together. I have `\tikzexternalize` in my preable to, so I keep figures in separate files after compiling each of them.

This is a big hassle. How can I get pgfplots alignment and avoid this issue?

Here's a MWE that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        scale only axis
    },
    /tikz/every picture/.append style={
        trim axis left,
        trim axis right,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[very thick,->] (-1,-1) -- (1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code explicitly requests to apply the bounding box modifications for *every* picture.

I suppose the correct solution is to write a *named* style (i.e. something like `trimmed picture` instead of `every picture`) and use that named style explicitly in every picture for which it is to be applied (i.e. `\begin{tikzpicture}[trimmed pictured]`).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this leads to spacing issues or others, but just adding an empty axis to every picture gets rid of the error:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\pgfplotsset{
    every axis/.append style={
        scale only axis
    },
    /tikz/execute at begin picture={
        \begin{axis}, \end{axis},
    }    
    /tikz/every picture/.append style={
        trim axis left,
        trim axis right,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[very thick,->] (-1,-1) -- (1,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=0:360] {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you can get away with it if you make sure that no grid and axis lines are drawn in the dummy axis.

Comment: @percuße I don't think I understood what you meant. Shouldn't the empty axis be enough? Is there any way to force no grid nor axis in this empty axis?

Comment: @perr0 Well, if you also include `every axis` stiff those dummy axes would effected too. So it's best to include the nondrawing axis lines and grid lines as precautions.

Comment: @percuße so, the code you suggest would be different from this one?